# Trouble understanding simple recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion

My function:

```
int num(int x) 
{ 
   if(x>0) 
     num(x-1); 
   else 
     return 0; 
   printf("%d",x); 
}
```

This function takes a input x and prints the numbers from 1 upto x.I can't seem to understand how this works, can someone please elaborate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume it wasn't you who wrote the function. If I call int x = num (10), there is undefined behaviour. The return type should be void, and it shouldn't return anything in the else part. Awful code.

Comment: @gnasher729 I originally wrote this code(with some modification) to find the multiplication table of a number n. It worked fine for my purpose but I didn't know the code blows(since I'm in the early learning phase of recursion). Thanks

Comment: Not related to the question, but recursion isn't the right tool for what you're using it for.  A loop will handle an arbitrarily-large number without growing the stack on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks,I know,I just wanted to flex my "recursion muscles"since I understand iteration properly.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this type of thing, it's often best to take a pen and paper and "pretend to be the computer running the code".

So, if we have a call of `num(4)`, it will lead to:

```
if (4 > 0)    // Yupp, 4 > 0 
  num(3);     // x - 1 = 3
  if (3 > 0)  // Yupp
    num(2)
    if (2 > 0)
      num(1)
      if (1 > 0)
        num(0)
        if (0 > 0) // Nope
        goto else-part:
        return 0;
      skip else-part
      print(1);
    skip else-part
    print(2);
  skip else-part
  print(3)
  skip else-part
print(4)
```

Comment: @Malt It's confusing because of I place the print statement inside if statement inside braces just before the function call, my output is from x to 1. But when I place the print statement inside if statement inside braces just after the function call, my output is from 1 to x. Can you please elaborate the functioning? Thanks.

Comment: Follow the logic. If you put the print at the beginning of the function, the calls to `num(3)`, `num(2)` etc happens after printing, so obviously, values printed will be "high to low". If you place it after the call to `num` - either in the if or at the end, it will print in "low to high" order.

Answer (score 3):

in my opinion, the easiest way of wrapping your head around recursion is starting from the end.

In every recursive function, there's a stopping condition. In your case it's `else return 0;` so the method will return 0 if the argument is zero or lower. That's simple. Now let's go backwards.

We know that `num(0)` returns `0` without doing anything else. So now we can now figure out what `num(1)` is. `num(1)` will call `num(0)` (which will return 0 and do nothing else), and then print `x` which is `1`. Now we can backtrack and look at `num(2)`. `num(2)` will call `num(1)`, which we already covered, and then prints `2`, so we can look at `num(3)` etc.

So for every number `x`, num(x) will simply print all numbers from `1` to `x`.